# How to convert this class to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

It's my first time that i work with fragment and I want to convert this code into a fragment 
this is my code

public class CONNECTION extends AppCompatActivity 
   {

```
EditText editText;


private static final String SEND_DATA_URL = "jjj";

Spinner spinner;
String I,Ename,Ecity;
String DEF="NA";

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connection);

    textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView100);

    spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner8);
  ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,       R.array.connect, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText22);
    ////////////////////////


}

public void send(View view) {

    CheckInternetConnection cic = new CheckInternetConnection(getApplicationContext());
    Boolean Ch = cic.isConnectingToInternet();
    if (!Ch){
        Toast.makeText(CONNECTION.this, "no conncection ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


private void openProfile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(CONNECTION.this, CONNECTION.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}




    }
}}`
```

I want an example in this code so i can change the other class's

Comment: There is an example https://github.com/OmniDebt/OmniDebt-Android/wiki/Convert-Activity-to-Fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert activities to fragments android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171670/how-to-convert-activities-to-fragments-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.connection, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

   textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView100);

  spinner=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner8);
  ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.connect, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
  spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
  editText=(EditText)viewfindViewById(R.id.editText22);
  }   
}
```

Then add your all remaining methods and variables from Activity to Fragment. After this load this Fragment in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the **`Fragment`** is in a separate class. To make that class a **`Fragment`** class add **`extends Fragment`** after the class name. Make sure to override the **`onCreateView()`** method in your fragment class. Any more questions?